# Shorthand to Register Handler of Event

Tags: c#, .net-core

Can the following Code be simplified to make the constructor of the ViewModel obsolete?

```
class MainViewModel
{
    public StandardIntCommand Change { get; set; } = new StandardIntCommand();

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Change.Executed += Change_Executed;
    }

    private void Change_Executed(object sender, int e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Is there some sort of Lambda expression or another way where something like this would work:

```
public StandardIntCommand Change { get; set; } = new StandardIntCommand() {=> Executed += Change_Executed};
```

Which would make this obsolete:

```
public MainViewModel()
    {
        Change.Executed += Change_Executed;
    }
```

Comment: What is _StandardIntCommand_?

Comment: There's no syntax like the object initalizer that attaches event handlers at instantiation. In fact, because `Change`'s `set` accessor is public, rather than being auto-implemented, it should detach the event handler from the previous instance and attach it to the new instance. You're trying to reduce code when you actually need *more* code.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you probably point to some resources covering the "detaching the event handler", as I am not familiar with this issue

Comment: Resources are scarce since it's not a very common problem. You need to reimplement the `Change` property with explicit backing field (e.g. `_change`) and accessors, and the `set` accessor essentially does `_change.Executed -= Change_Executed; _change = value; _change.Executed += Change_Executed;`, with appropriate equality and null checking that I've conveniently omitted. That way the event handler no longer can be called by the old instance and instead can be called by the new instance. And since it's the opposite direction of the question you asked, I won't write it as an answer.